# Running .NET Application on Windows PE Powershell

Tags: .net, powershell, winpe

I have written a basic .NET application with two buttons and two labels to automatically execute several batch files. The program works correctly on Windows and on Window's powershell.

However, I have created a Windows PE USB with PowerShell and when I try to start up my application from Windows PE using Powershell 5.0 I get the following error:

`Program "WinImageSetup.exe" failed to run: The subsystem needed to support the image type is not presentAt line: 1 char: 1
+ E:\WinImageSetup.exe
+-------------------
At line:1 char:1
+ E:\WinImageSetup.exe
+--------------------
+CategoryInfo: ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
+FullyQualifiedErrorId: NativeCommandFailed`

Is there anything I am missing to run a .NET application from Windows PE Powershell?

Comment: I can't find a reference but im sure .Net assemblies are not present in earlier versions of WinPE. Adding what version of PE you are using might be helpful

Comment: Windows PE 5.0 @Matt

Comment: Have you looked at [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/hh824926.aspx) which has a section that talks about dependencies and "_WinPE-NetFX contains a subset of the .NET Framework 4.5_"

Comment: Yes, that is the tutorial I followed to create the USB Windows PE with Powershell. I thought maybe I messed up one of the steps and repeated the process, but still cannot run the .exe @Matt

Comment: I just tested a .vbs script file and it worked perfectly, even showing the GUI I made for it. Maybe this means .NET programs are not executable from that environment? @Matt

Comment: .Net in PE is not the full .net. That link show that some components are not present. All depends what you program does and how it was coded.

Comment: WPF is not supporterd in WinPE. WinForms is supported. How did you wrote your app ?